# Should an autorelease call crash if there is no nsautoreleasepool declared?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I am sorry, I am new with cocoa programming and I am not sure if I really understand how nsautoreleasepool works.

Everywhere I read says something about the NSAutoreleasePool are responsable for all autorelease calls (talking about the last NSAutoreleasePool declared).

Considering the follow code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    //[pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

at some point of my application I would also have something close to this:

```
NSString* b = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 10];
[b autorelease];
```

Considering that I don't have `NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` anywhere... shouldnt the `[b autorelease];` crashs the application? But the application seems to work fine apparently.

Observation: I have no intention of writing an application without NSAutoreleasePool, I just want to get well the idea of how that works. This fact made doubt about what I thought I knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll simply get a warning in the console that there's no autorelease pool and that the object was leaked.

If you really want to understand autorelease pools, read [Mike Ash's *Let's build NSAutoreleasePool*](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-02-lets-build-nsautoreleasepool.html).

Comment: That is not happening.

When I touch the button I am calling:

    NSString* b = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 10];
    [b autorelease];


I have NSLog and UIAlert I am sure the method is being called... and it shows me no error in the console, nothing as if there was nothing wrong.

Comment: Ah, I think what you're doing "wrong" here is that you have a runloop already running (`UIApplicationMain`). Replace the `UIApplicationMain` line with `[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 10] autorelease];` and you'll get the leak message. You'll also get it if you create a new thread (for example via `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`) and running your autorelease test without creating an autorelease pool first.

Comment: (PS: The runloop creates autorelease pools, which is why your object was in fact not leaking)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `NSAutoreleasePool`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

> In a reference counted environment, Cocoa expects there to be an
>   autorelease pool always available. If a pool is not available,
>   autoreleased objects do not get released and you leak memory. In this
>   situation, your program will typically log suitable warning messages.

That's pretty self explanatory. Are you getting any messages related to this logged in the console?

Comment: No, I didnt. That is what I found weird. I commented the declaration of NSAutorelease pool at the main method and I called [b autorelease] and I see no warning or error messange on the console or anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> the NSApplication class sets up autorelease pools (instances of the
>   NSAutoreleasePool class) during initialization and inside the event
>   loop—specifically, within its initialization (or sharedApplication)
>   and run methods. Similarly, the methods the Application Kit adds to
>   NSBundle employ autorelease pools during the loading of nib files.
>   These autorelease pools aren’t accessible outside the scope of the
>   respective NSApplication and NSBundle methods. Typically, an
>   application creates objects either while the event loop is running or
>   by loading objects from nib files, so this lack of access usually
>   isn’t a problem. However, if you do need to use Cocoa classes within
>   the main() function itself (other than to load nib files or to
>   instantiate NSApplication), you should create an autorelease pool
>   before using the classes and then release the pool when you’re done.
>   For more information, see [NSAutoreleasePool in the Foundation
>   Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAutoreleasePool).

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationMain()` makes sure the main thread runs an event loop, so your app can process events (e.g. user input, timer events, etc.) and the event loop creates an autoreleasepool before starting its iteration and releases it once its done wit it. All code that is called from the even loop of the main thread (e.g. all UI code) always has an autoreleasepool in place, there is nothing you would have to do. You only need to manage the autoreleasepool when using a thread different than the main thread (but only when actually using a thread! When using DispatchQueues or OperationQueues, these will also manage the autoreleasepool for you) and in some rare cases you want to use them around loops to keep your memory footprint small (an autoreleasepool collects objects for later release but sometimes you don't want it to collect too many objects and thus become too big, instead you want to clear it on every iteration of your own loop, in that case you'd need to manage one yourself). In most cases you don't need to know anything about autoreleasepools, you can write an entire, full features app without every having heard of autoreleasepools. You only need to know when you must call `autorelease` on an object you own and this only applies to non-ARC code as with ARC the compiler will decide that for you automatically.